# How should we decide on the number of virtual processors and RAM required in VMWare

Tags: vmware

Can someone help with this question:
Would like to know how to make decision on number of virtual processors and RAM required  in VMWare -
Database hosted:SQLServer
Min Storage :600 GB

Answer (score 0):

That's a pretty open question. There's a lot of dependencies that would impact how much CPU/RAM would be needed.

Perhaps you can start by reading this: https://www.vmware.com/content/dam/digitalmarketing/vmware/en/pdf/solutions/sql-server-on-vmware-best-practices-guide.pdf